# How to compare two numbers to decide a winner?

Tags: python

So this is what I have so far:

```
dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
dice2 = random.randrange(6) + 1

total = dice1 + dice2
```

I need to compare the totals so that I can say that one player has a higher total than, and thus beats, another player. How can I compare two scores so that the higher one can come out as the winner? Also how do I incorporate the fact that there maybe a tie and thus multiple winners?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
if dice1 > dice2:
  print "dice1 wins"
elif dice1 < dice2:
  print "dice2 wins"
else:
  print "dice are equal"
```

Comment: What about if there is a tie? You need to use an ```elif```.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
from random import randrange

# this method simulates rolling two dies at the same time
def roll_dice(): 
    return randrange(7) + randrange(7) 

player1 = roll_dice()
player2 = roll_dice()

if player1 > player2:
    print("Player one wins")
elif player2 > player1:
    print("Player two wins")
else:
    print("Tie")
```

To simulate rolling a pair of dice, I return the sum of two random rolls. Then I use some if statements (conditional logic) to check which player had the higher roll or whether the roll was a tie.

Comment: Use [```random.randrange()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) instead of ```random.choice(range())```.

Comment: Good idea, I don't know why I thought it would be better to call range in choice